# PHP require_once error

Tags: php, html, coda

I am using CODA, MAMP and am working out of my HTdocs folder all locally.  I am learning PHP and MVC structure and an coming across the following error when using require_once. I have read many of the other posts on this topic and no solution has worked.

The error I am receiving is:

```
Warning: require_once(UserModel.php): failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in - on line 13 Fatal error: require_once():
Failed opening required 'UserModel.php' (include_path='.:') in - on line 13
```

My file structure is:

```
database
----bdfdatabase.sql
index.php
UserModel.php
```

My code is as follows

```
<?php   
    require_once('UserModel.php');

    $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=bdfdatabase";
    $db_user= "root";
    $db_pass= "root";
    $model = new UserModel($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $rows = $model->displayUsers();

        foreach($rows as $row){
            echo "<h3><a href='details.php'>";
            echo "${row['user_name']}";
            echo "</a></h3>";
        }

?>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: SO your require_once is in index.php?

Comment: "`... in - on line 13`"...? How are you running this code?

Comment: @Starx Yes, My require_once is in index.php.

Comment: And you are probably using a linux platform?

Comment: Can you try create a new project again and copy paste the files in the new project? Maybe it's your configuration setting. I never used coda but is there any part where coda ask you to specify an index.php file when you create a new project?

Comment: @Standstill I attempted to copy and paste all the files a recreate the directory but still getting the error.  Coda does not have a project creator.. just create whatever file type you need.

Comment: @Garret You have addressed all but the most important question: *how exactly are you running that file?*

Comment: @deceze I am unsure of the question.  I am on Mac OS using MAMP and Coda as my text editor. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So are you looking at it in a browser, pointed to `localhost:8888/something`? Are you just hitting the preview function in Coda? Is the "in - on line 13" accurate, or did you redact the "`-`"?

Comment: I was hitting the preview in Coda.. the error code is accurate as well.  I did just attempt to run the file using localhost/etc.. the PHP still does not run.

Comment: And you're getting the same error, "in - on line 13"? That error should point to the file and line of the `require_once` statement. But "-" is weird and that doesn't seem to be line 13 either.

Comment: It is line 13.. i did not include the html doctype and so on in the code I posted.. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, The problem is once again the **Path**.

1. Make sure `UserModel.php` lies in the same folder as the one from which you are running the above code.
2. Make sure you have access to read that file. The file must be readable by owners, group, and others, to be included as such. Change the mode of the file to `0774` to confirm this.

Comment: I changed the mode to 0774 and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Garrett, `0774` is the minimum permission needed to read the file. and Try `0775` Once and if all else fails `0777` is the only way you can do in some hosting plans.

Comment: I have tried all of the above with no success.  Many of the other posts talk of the dirname and __FILE__.  I have attempted these with no success also